# JQuery , adding div dynamically with error message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the below json response from an validation api  , the first attribute is the id of each input field  with the error message.

```
{
    "backgroundcolor": "Color is not Supported",
    "terms" : "Sorry the Terms are blank"
}
```

I am using jquery and bootstrap and want to append the below html just after each input field of that specific id . Is this possible to add div dynamically ?

```
<div id="backgroundcolor" class="invalid-feedback">
  Color is not Supported
</div>
```

Before :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="backgroundcolor" aria-describedby="validationServer03Feedback" required>
</div>
```

After :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="backgroundcolor" aria-describedby="validationServer03Feedback" required>
<div id="backgroundcolorFeedBack" class="invalid-feedback">
  Color is not Supported.
</div>
```

Comment: **Ids must be unique** -- you cannot have `div#backgroundcolor` and `input#backgroundcolor` on the same page. When you try (I assume you are using jQuery/JavaScript) to reference `#backgroundcolor` the browser will always assume that there is only one id on the page so once it finds the first`#backgroundcolor` it stops and goes no further. Please add jQuery and/or JavaScript as a [mcve] and read [ask]. When editing your question⏩[look for the brackets `<>` button](https://i.ibb.co/935zWhk/mcve.jpg)⏪

Comment: Please include the attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really help us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript alone is the best and fastest solution, so here it is how i would do it:

```
let response = JSON.parse(response);

let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
let child = document.createElement('div');
child.id = Object.keys(response)[0] + 'FeedBack';
child.className = 'invalid-feedback';
child.innerText = Object.values(response)[0];
fragment.appendChild(child);

document.getElementById(Object.keys(response)[0]).after(fragment);
```

I hope it'll help.

**Note:** createDocumentFragment() may be slightly faster than createElement alone, but it's not required.

**Edit:** you can also check if there is already div with that error, it would prevent duplication of divs

```
if(!document.getElementById(Object.keys(response)[0].length) {
    // Here goes code from above
}
```